# If $T(n) = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T(k),$ then $T(n) = 2^n.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

> Question: Let $T(n)$ be a running time that satisfies the recurrence 
>   $$T(n) = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T(k) \quad \text{and}\quad T(0) = 1.$$
>   Show that $T(n) = 2^n.$

The recurrence above can be obtained in CLRS's Introduction to Algorithms, $3$rd edition, page $364,$ where the authors discuss rod-cutting problem using Recursive top-down implementation.

Does anyone how to obtain the solution for the recurrence of $T(n)$ above?

Comment: You have to have some initial stage. Usually initial stage starts from $0$ where time is involved. So then you need to assume $T(0)=1.$ Otherwise you cannot get the required result.

Comment: @mathmaniac. added the initial condition.

Comment: It seems that both [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24T(n)%20%3D%201%20%2B%20%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D%20T(k)%24&p=1) and [with SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7BT(n)%20=%201%20%2B%20%5Csum_%7Bk=0%7D%5E%7Bn-1%7D%20T(k)%7D$) you can find some older posts about the same recurrence. Some general tips on searching: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: To list a few examples:
[How do you solve a recurrence with a summation function inside](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/530132),
[Prove that the sequence with $T(0)=1$ and $T(n) = 1 + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}T(j)$ is given by $T(n)=2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/892395),
[Solve $T(n) = 1 +\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}T(i)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/915070),
[Proving $T(n) = 1 + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} T(j)$, $T(0)=1$ implies $T(n)=2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1250636).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Set $n=m,m-1$  in  $$T(n) = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T(k).$$

$$T(m) = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} T(k).$$
$$T(m-1) = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{m-2} T(k)$$

$$T(m)-T(m-1)=?$$

$$\implies T(n)=2^{n-r}T(r)$$

Set $r=0,1$  based on the initial case

Comment: I see. Do you have any recommended books for practising solving recurrence for running time complexity? I find that my solving skills in running time recurrence are not up to bar.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common methods to solve these kinds of problems; [backward substitution method](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/BackSubstitutionMod.html) and [forward substitution method](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/BackSubstitutionMod.html). Most of the time the backward is more helpful. This one easy with forward.

$$T(n) = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} T(k) \quad \text{and}\quad T(0) = 1.$$ Let us expand it;

$T(n) =  T(n-1)+ T(n-2) + \cdots + T(1) + 1$ and if you look at from bottom

\begin{align}
T(0) & = 1 & &=1 & &  =1\\
T(1) & = T(0) +1 & &= 1 + 1  & &= 2\\
T(2) & = T(1) + T(0) +1 & &= 2 + 1 + 1 & &= 4 \\
T(3) & = T(2) + T(1) + T(0) +1& &= 4 + 2 + 1 + 1 & &= 8 \\
T(4) & = T(3) + T(2) + T(1) + T(0) +1 & &= 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 1 & &= 16\\
\end{align}

After some initial values if you see a pattern then you can set up your claim, here $T(n) = 2^{n}$, and the next step is proving this claim by induction...

Note that CLRS' Introduction to Algorithms mostly uses backward substitution even for the proof of Master Theorem of the analysis of algorithms.

Comment: I see. I am thinking that if this was an interview question, how should I approach it.